# How to use Google Map API in JavaEE?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jakarta-ee

I have a server application and in my My-SQL database I have stored coordinates(latitude, longitude). I want to use those coordinates to show polyline on the Map.

I was able to create a Map using Google Maps API, but in that I have to hard code coordinated to show a marker (or polyline) over there using script. How can I achieve this dynamic functionality?

Comment: Read about the vector formats Google Maps will ingest, followed by how to generate them using Java from a database and then come back with a more specific question.

Comment: can you share you code

Answer (score 0):

As Google Maps runs in a browser, you'll need to create a Java backend webservice which pulls the data from your database by certain parameters set by an AJAX request from the browser. As your question is quite vage, I can't really give you more details.

There should be a lot of examples to find via an appropriate Google search I guess. There an answer to a similar question here:

[populating google maps markers using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555766/populating-google-maps-markers-using-ajax)